# Convert from string with milliseconds to date object Javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I got this problem when dealing with date time conversion. I have timestamp data from postgreSQL database with format like this one

"2011-04-04 19:27:39.92034"

In order to display it in highcharts, I have to convert it to date or time object. Without milliseconds, I easily convert it with [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)

But milliseconds can't be handled with that library. I tried also with Date.parse but always got NaN.

Any solution for this problem? Thank you

Comment: Those are microseconds, not milliseconds and JavaScript time resolution starts with milliseconds.. so some accuracy will be lost. You need to extract that value, divide by 1000, append back to the string and follow one of the answers you got. Otherwise you'll have incorrect time.

Comment: oh, I'm so sorry. My bad. Thank you for correcting me, Shadow. Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try it.

Answer (score 9):

JS built in Date class should be able to handle this, and getTime() can return milliseconds since start 1970 (UNIX time). Watch out for time zone issues though; the constructor may interpret the date/time as being local, but getTime()'s milliseconds since 1970 may be in UTC, baking in a conversion that is difficult to remove.

```
new Date("2011-04-04 19:27:39.92034").getTime()
1301941659920
```

Comment: Not in Safari, Opera or Firefox (and maybe others, that's all I tested). You have to replace the hyphen with forward slash and remove the decimal seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to Rome. The given code will return '(datestr=) 2011-4-4 19:27:39.92'. Is that what you look for?

```
var darr = '2011-04-04 19:27:39.92034'.split('.')
  , dat=new Date(darr[0])
  , datestr = '';
dat.setMilliseconds(Math.round(darr[1]/1000));
datestr = [ [dat.getFullYear(),dat.getMonth()+1,dat.getDate()].join('-')
            ,' ', 
            [dat.getHours(),dat.getMinutes(),dat.getSeconds()].join(':')
            ,'.',
            dat.getMilliseconds()
          ].join('');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Kooilnc. I tried your code and I got NaN but after I replace '-' with '/' in variable darr, it worked. Anyway, your code is really inspired me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just cut of the last 6 chars of that string? You might then round the miliseconds and eventually add a second to you time object.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler and in one line:

```
new Date('01/09/2015 06:16:14.123'.split(".")[0])
```