# Can i use sub-second samples and still have nice dates in dygraph?

Tags: javascript, csv, sampling, dygraphs, milliseconds

Currently, I'm using a dygraph instance on a website, feeding it with data submitted via CSV.

My problem is, I'm trying to plot fast processes with sampling rates exceeding 100 per second.

I tried to change my CSV format from:

```
 date,val1,val2
 2016/11/26 11:11:11,2.0,3.0
 2016/11/26 11:11:12,3.0,4.0
```

To:

```
 2016/11/26 11:11:11.005,2.0,3.0
 2016/11/26 11:11:11.042,2.5,3.5
 2016/11/26 11:11:11.512,2.8,3.8
 2016/11/26 11:11:12.015,3.0,4.0
```

But the graph won't show up. I read the doc and noticed `For dates, your strings have to be parseable by Date.parse` in http://dygraphs.com/data.html, which to my understanding hinders a sub-second resolution. Is there any way to circumvent this.

I'm well aware, that I could just use the milisecond timestamps on the x-axis, but by this I'll loose the nice dates below the graph.

Or can someone point me to another graph library, which fits my needs (sub-second sampling, free for commercial use)

Comment: Does it work if you change `11:042` to `11.042`? `Date.parse` is able to parse dates with milliseconds.

Comment: Just tried this. Here's some example data:
     time,TTI (%)
     2016/11/29 15:55:50:000,10
     2016/11/29 15:55:50:050,20
     2016/11/29 16:04:59:321,25
     2016/11/30 10:12:18:000,23
     2016/11/30 10:20:23:000,23
     2016/11/30 10:20:58:000,23
     2016/11/30 10:23:14:000,23
     2016/11/30 10:26:00:000,23
     2016/11/30 10:26:23:000,23
     2016/11/30 10:30:22:000,23
doesn't work, either

Comment: Try changing "2016/11/29 15:55:50:000" to "2016/11/29 15:55:50.000" (colon → period). At least in my browser, the one parses as a date while the other doesn't.

Comment: 'This was what my original dataset looked like. Just noticed, that i had some colons AND some periods in the original question. Will correct this.

Comment: Actually the format YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss.mili works in Chromium (and Chrome I guess) but not in firefox. Need to find out, whether there's an open bug report somewhere for this javascript issue.
related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538485/convert-from-string-with-milliseconds-to-date-object-javascript#5538518

Comment: Ah, i should have seen this: http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html